# Restricting permissions of threads that execute third party software

Tags: java, multithreading, permissions, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse based application capable of executing third party components (not eclipse-plugin).

Each component has a custom descriptor that lists permissions (with corresponding motivation). In this way the end user can decide to execute it or not.

Components are executed in separate threads. How can I restrict permissions of these threads according to the descriptor, without restricting entire application?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should turn on the Security Manager. Then create an [AccessControlContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessControlContext.html) with the desired permissions. (No permissions in my example.) Finally execute the third party code in the [AccessController.doPrivileged(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged%28java.security.PrivilegedAction,%20java.security.AccessControlContext%29) method.

This is a very simple solution:

```
public abstract class SafeRunnable implements Runnable {

public abstract void protectedRun();

@Override
public final void run() {
    CodeSource nullSource = new CodeSource(null, (CodeSigner[]) null);
    PermissionCollection noPerms = new Permissions();
    ProtectionDomain domain = new ProtectionDomain(nullSource, noPerms);
    AccessControlContext safeContext = new AccessControlContext(
            new ProtectionDomain[] { domain });

    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
        public Object run() {
            protectedRun();
            return null;
        }
    }, safeContext);
}
}
```

Testing the SafeRunnable:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // Turn on the security management
    SecurityManager sm = new SecurityManager();
    System.setSecurityManager(sm);

    new Thread(new SafeRunnable() {
        public void protectedRun() {
            // friendly operation:
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new SafeRunnable() {
        public void protectedRun() {
            // malicious operation
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

First thread prints Hello, the second throws `AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM.0")`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Starting from your example I tried to add a permission in noPerms with 'noPerms.add(new FilePermission("/", "read"));' statement, but permission doesn't affect if I try to list directory files.