# How to restrict access to a method by a specific thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

In an interview I was asked to come up with an approach which will ensure that while thread T1 and T3 can access a method of a class, T2 cannot access the method.

I am unable to provide any solution to this. Could you please provide an example with an explanation?

I have later come up with the following solution. Is it efficient?

```
package JavaProgramming;

public class EligibleThread implements Runnable {

    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EligibleThread t1 = new EligibleThread();
        EligibleThread t2 = new EligibleThread();
        Thread t11 = new Thread(t1, "t1");
        Thread t22 = new Thread(t2, "t2");
        t11.start();
        t22.start();

    }

    public void run() {
        if (Thread.currentThread().getName() != "t2") {
            method1();
        } else{
            try {
                throw new Exception("Access is denied");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't quite sound thread-related. How do you prevent access from a certain place, but allow access from another? :)

Comment: @DreamspacePresident Based on your comment, later on I came up with the above code snippet (included in my post).

Comment: I think you've provided an OK solution. But see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516766/restrict-permissions-to-threads-which-execute-third-party-software

Answer (score 0):

You can use protected modifier, like following code. T1 can call aMethod() by extending Main class, but T2 can't call aMethod().

```
public class Main {
    protected void aMethod() {

    }
}

class T1 extends Main implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        aMethod();
    }
}

class T2 implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // here can't call Main.aMethod()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sam for your answer.